# fontfamily not plotting the same for ylab and xlab in lattice plots

Tags: r, lattice, font-family

I am trying to change the font for several lattice plots to "Times New Roman" and after specifying the fontfamily in a new theme, both the xlab and ylab plot in Time New Roman, but the ylab is always slightly different (thinner and lighter).

Here is my code for importing and confirming the presence of the font, setting the fontfamily in a new theme, and an example of a plot:

```
library(lattice)
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)      
font_import()                 # import fonts
loadfonts(device="win")       # Register fonts for Windows bitmap output
fonts()                       # "Times New Roman" is available

font.settings <- list(
  fontfamily = "Times New Roman")
my.theme <- list(
  par.xlab.text = font.settings,
  par.ylab.text = font.settings,
  axis.text = font.settings,
  sub.text = font.settings,
  add.text = font.settings)

dat <- data.frame(year = as.factor(rep(seq(2001, 2004,1),20)), cw = rep(1:20,4),
    ch = rep(1:20,4))
xyplot(ch ~ cw | year, data = dat,
    ylab = "This is y-label", xlab = "This is x-label",
    layout = c(2,2),
    par.settings = my.theme)
```

The ylab looks different then the xlab on screen and when saved as pdf, png, etc.

I've confirmed that the theme for the par.settings is responsive to different parameters using the code below (just for an example), so it seems that the par.xlab.text and par.ylab.test are working.

```
font.settings <- list(
  fontfamily = "Times New Roman")
font.settings2 <- list(
  fontfamily = "Perpetua",
  col = "red")
my.theme <- list(
  par.xlab.text = font.settings2,
  par.ylab.text = font.settings,
  axis.text = font.settings,
  sub.text = font.settings,
  add.text = font.settings)
```

I've followed the methods in Lattice by Deepayan Sarkar in Chapter 7 and get similar results.

Thanks in advance